# Probability that an activity will finish first

Tags: probability

Suppose, we have 3 activities **a,b,c**. Each activity has (uniform) **random duration** from interval <10;20>. At time t, we start an activity **c**, while the other ones are already running. Activities **a** and **b** have started at different point of time so the  elapsed time of an activity **a** is **x** and elapsed time of an activity **b** is **y**. What is the probability, that an **activity c will finish first**?

Comment: So you mean that $a$ has started at time $t-x$ ?

Comment: @Zubzub yes, and _b_ has started at time _t - y_

Comment: Hints: 1) $c$ beats $a$ w.p. $P[U_c < U_a - x]$. 2) The probability $c$ finishes first is the probability he beats both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @msitt so if both a,b have elapsed time 5, then resulting probability would be [baseProb - (5/10)*baseProb]^2? where baseProb is probability, that C beats other activity if they started at the same time i.e. 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start. Hopefully I didn't messed up the different cases. You should be able to complete.

Let $A,B,C \sim U([10,20])$ denote the time taken by the activity. I assume that activity $c$ starts at time $t$ while $a$ has been already running for $x$ unit of time and $b$ has already been running for $y$ unit of time, $x,y$ being fixed non-negative constants.

We want :
$$
Pr[C < A-x \wedge C < B-y] \overset{(*)}{=} Pr[C < A-x] \cdot Pr[C < B-y]
$$
$(*)$ By independence.

Let's now focus on 
$$
Pr[C < A-x] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dc \int_{c+x}^\infty da\ f_{A,C}(a,c) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty dc \int_{c+x}^\infty da\ f_{A}(a)f_{C}(c) = \\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dc\ f_C(c) \underbrace{\int_{c+x}^\infty da\ f_A(a)}_{(I)}
$$
$$
(I) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } c > 20-x \\
1 & \text{if } c < 10-x \\
\frac{c+x-10}{10} &\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Now we rewrite the integral by splitting its domain $\mathbb{R}$ :
$$
Pr[C < A-x] \overset{(**)}{=} 
\int_{-\infty}^{10-x} f_C(c)\cdot (I) dc + \int_{10-x}^{20-x} f_C(c)\cdot (I) dc +  \int_{20-x}^{\infty} f_C(c)\cdot (I) dc \overset{(***)}{=} \\
0 + \int_{10-x}^{20-x} f_C(c)\cdot \frac{x+c-10}{10} dc + 0 \overset{(****)}{=} \\ 
\int_{10-x}^{10} f_C(c)\cdot \frac{x+c-10}{10} dc + \int_{10}^{20-x} f_C(c)\cdot \frac{x+c-10}{10} dc = 0+ \int_{10}^{20-x} f_C(c)\cdot \frac{x+c-10}{10} dc= \\
\int_{10}^{20-x} \frac{c-10}{10}\cdot \frac{x+c-10}{10} dc
$$
$(**)$ Splitting the $\mathbb{R}$ domain.

$(***)$ Plugging $(I)$.

$(****)$ Splitting the $[10-x,20-x]$ domain.

Then you can compute very similarily $Pr[C < B-y]$.

Comment: I was hoping it is much easier so when I saw your answer i was like [reaction](http://www.reactiongifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/tom-delonge-wtf1.gif) :), but yours steps looks right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you ca get rid of many split-cases by simply assuming $0\leq x \leq 20$ since we assume $x$ positive and clearly if $x \geq 20$ then the probability is $0$ since $a$ will have finished :)